# Can i deploy rails project without Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

**Problem:** I have rails project runing in server A. I want to move this project to server B. But gemfile is missing in the source code in Server A

**Question:** 
1. can i deploy this project without Gemfile? 
- if yes please share me how.
- else: is there any solution to recreate Gemfile which have same env with current server?
2. I wanna upgrade ruby, rails. Will it take a lot of time to upgrade to the lastest version?

Answer (score 1):

> can i deploy this project without Gemfile?

probably, but it is likely to be very painful and the only way I can think that it could work would be to manually install all the gems you need, which probably isn't that great for you, since your Gemfile is missing, and I presume that you didn't have it memorized.

> is there any solution to recreate Gemfile which have same env with current server?

check and see if theres a Gemfile.lock, you should hopefully be able to recreate your Gemfile from that, since it should list your dependencies and their version ranges. Other then that, you can try generating a new rails project, and copying that Gemfile, and then adding any Gems you know it uses to that, and then either running tests (if you have them) or doing manual tests to see if it breaks because of a missing gem.

> I wanna upgrade ruby, rails. Will it take a lot of time to upgrade to the lastest version?

Depends on what version of Ruby and Rails your currently on and also how big and complex your project is. Hard to say without knowing your project, but you can check the upgrade guides for Rails. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html